# How to build manually a form submit request in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My problem is to follow the 'normal' way of building a form, submitting it to an Action on the server.

After verifying data, I have a ValidationSummary where to show eventual errors, and so on...

Now, I want to post to the server a Json object, instead of a form.

The fact is that I'm using a Kendo MVVM observable object that mimics the input controls, and it's kept in sync with them, so I would like to send this object to the server, a thing that I can do easily with a 'normal' post, but then, I'm stuck with the current (version of the) page, without validation and without reloading the page.

Keeping things (and problems!) separate, I don't know in the end how to build manually a submit request (passing Json data and following the default ASP.NET MVC flow): any solution I found out doesn't seem (for what I know) to exploit the same functionality.

I hope to have been clear, with my problem... :-)

Thanks in advance

Andrea

Comment: Why cant you translate your mvvm model into your view's model and continue posting as you have been?

Comment: Ok, this surely confirms that I'm quite stupid... Thanks for pointing it out! :-) A normal submit sends all of the controls' values... so my question was really nonsense!